# Entitlements.plist Not Right

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I generate an Entitlements.plist the contents are like this

```
    <key>application-identifier</key>
   <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
   <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
   <array>
       <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
   </array>
```

Instead of being like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I generate an Entitlements.plist"? You shouldn't need to generate them yourself.

Comment: @tc, I click File -> New -> Code Signing -> Entitlements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has changed the entitlements to the new version you are seeing now. You are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Hi, I just looked again, it was a TechNote on developer.apple.com, I cant find the page again. But they say the entitlements has changed 100% positive.

If you are generating an entitlements file for xcode 3.2.3 or IOs 4 you wont need to if you are doing ad-hoc app sharing.

After much testing. I found I had to make a new ad-hoc certificate with the correct bundle id. eg for me it was
nz.co.bluespark.myapp
Download and install

Then without adding any entitlements, in xcode, I set my project to 
debug, device, 
build > build & archive

Then share in organiser, sign with new cert.